Unable to connect to multiple host in postgres : missing = after \"host1,\" in connection info string
I want to make connection in postgres with this dsn format:
user=username password=password host=host1, host2, host3 port=5432 database=db_aob sslmode=prefer target_session_attrs=read-write
but i got error "missing "=" after "host1," in connection info string"
i try to remove space between host, but i got error "dial tcp: lookup host1,host2,host3: no such host"
is my dsn format wrong?
i connect with package database/sql in golang

The no-space version is correct for other drivers like libpq. Which PostgreSQL driver are you using with database/sql? lib/pq, for example (not to be confused with libpq…), doesn’t support multiple hosts.

i use lib/pq v1.10.0
i try to change the connection with url "postgres://username:password@host1,host2,host3:5432/dbname?target_session_attrs=read-write&sslmode=prefer"
and i still got error no such host

Right, it’s not going to work, I was just saying what the right syntax is for libraries that do support it.

The PostgreSQL driver you’re using, lib/pq, doesn’t support multiple hosts. You’ll need to use a different driver, like jackc/pgx, which does:

ParseConfig supports specifying multiple hosts in similar manner to libpq. Host and port may include comma separated values that will be tried in order. This can be used as part of a high availability system.


i already change libraries with jackc/pgx, but there is func migrate.ExecMax() in existing modules from package ("github.com/rubenv/sql-migrate") which require *sql.DB param. how can i replace that with pgx connection?

You can use github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib for that. PGX gives you the choice of working with database/sql or using PGX directly (better access to PostgreSQL specific functionality and, potentially, better performance).

@chirzulmaula what Brits said ^
